# Consultar último registro de una tabla en mysql solo si el id autoincremento aumenta

Tags: java, mysql

Necesito consultar la última fila de una base de datos MySql en java, pero solo la quiero mostrar si es nueva, o sea, si el ID autoincremento aumentó, ya tengo la última fila, pero no necesito mostrar la misma fila varias veces:

```java
PreparedStatement pps = cn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM documentos_a_descargar ORDER BY ID DESC");
```

Recojo la fila como un arreglo donde la posición 0 es el ID, y necesito mostrar un JOptionPane.showMessageDialog solo si ID aumentó.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

establece el límite de tu consulta a un resultado para obtener el último registro:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1
```

Si el id aumentó, puedes saberlo comparándolo con un registro anterior que puedes guardar a través de variable.  Si no coincide, muestras el JOP